# Upload photo taken with camera on phone using BlueImp JQuery Fileupload

Tags: jquery, mobile, blueimp

I'm trying to allow camera photo uploads from an Android device (would like it to support iPhone as well, but my main concern is getting it working with Android at the moment).  I'm using BlueImp's JQuery File Upload plugin, and it's working fine on desktop.  On mobile, when I take a picture with the camera, it shows the uploading happening (I have a progress bar) but the "done" function never actually fires.

I should note that I can select a photo that's already saved on the mobile device and upload that just fine, it's only when I select the "Camera" option from the popup menu that it fails.

This is on Android 4.4.4 using Chrome

Javascript:

```
$photoUpload.fileupload({
    url: '/image/uploadimage/',
    dataType: 'json',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    done: function (e, data) {

        var $formImageUpload =  $(this).parents('.form');
        $formImageUpload.find('.imageUrl').val(data.result.filePath).attr('type', 'hidden');
        $formImageUpload.find('.photoPreview').attr('src', data.result.filePath).show();
        $formImageUpload.find('.buttonResetImageForm').show();

    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var $formImageUpload =  $(this).parents('.form');

        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $formImageUpload.find('.progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: have a look at  the Chrome Filesystem API where you can save and retrieve files on the device -- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was completely unrelated to blueimp.  It was a size restriction, server-side.  Once I changed NGINX and PHP-FPM configuration to allow bigger files, it worked fine.